# When writing a internet browser in java

Tags: java, browser, editor

I came across the problem of not having an editor kit that could not handle some parts of a webpage. Examples include javascript and css. Does anyone know where I can find an editor kit that is suitable for that?
Also I'm curious as to what programming language browsers like Google Chrome and IE use.

Comment: *"internet browser"* .. *"an editor kit"*  Just because a `JEditorPane` can render simple HTML/CSS, please don't confuse it with an internet browser.  It is not one, and never will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Aptana Studio](http://aptana.com/products/studio3)

Answer (score 1):

There are already miscellaneous browser projects using java. The java Scripting API supporting undermore JavaScript (JS sometime named ECMAScript) will be worth looking into. You should on reading the HTML, construct a DOM tree and interprete `<script>` blocks, which may operate on the DOM or write HTML you have to read from.

The EditorKit in swing builds a too simple non.tree StyledDocument, which you have to bridge.

The way to proceed would be to first not use swing output but immediately generate a DOM/generated HTML.